Access peer dependency types in pnpm without making package a direct dependency
I use lib A, which has a peer dependency upon lib B. In my app code, I'd like to pull types from lib B, but pnpm's setup of the node_modules/ directory (at least out of the box) breaks this, the module in whole is unavailable.
How do I configure pnpm to let me access peer dependency types? It makes no sense to add B as a direct dependency as I don't use it as a direct dependency in any capacity at runtime.

Turns out it's the poorly named shamefully-hoist option (with little in the way to describe how it differs from hoist, which is enabled by default) in the incorrectly named .npmrc.
Docs: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#shamefully-hoist

It's really a shame that pnpm does not make this clear, tt seems like they just ignore the real use case.
